# How can I make Firefox Menu and Toolbar stop flashing?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, toolbar, hardware-acceleration

After a recent Firefox update, all of my menus and bookmarks toolbar have begun to flash when they're accessed. The content shows for a moment, but then I only see the outline and whatever was underneath shows through.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to have something to do with the browser's use of hardware acceleration.

In my case, disabling hardware acceleration in the browser resolved the problem.

To do this:

1. Open the Options screen (Firefox menu at the top, then Options -> Options).
2. Select the 'Advanced' Pane and then the 'General' Tab.
3. In the Browsing section, locate the checkbox for 'Use hardware acceleration when available'.
4. Ensure this box is NOT checked.
5. Click OK and restart your browser.

Following these steps made my problem go away.

Comment: +1 I had the same symptoms and this is what fixed it for me.